# What makes a good control variable?

Tags: controlling-for-a-variable

I am currently studying whether academic freedom (independant variable) has an impact on university rankings (independant variable). So far, my model is only composed of these two variables, as well as university fixed effects.

In order to get a better estimation, I am currently looking for control variables to include in my model (the problem being that there is almost no litterature on the topic, so I have to pick them out myself instead on relying on what previous authors chose).

I was wondering : what do I have to look for in order to determine whether the control variables I picked are well suited for my model ? I know that the control variables should be correlated with both my dependant and independant variable, but apart from this, I'm not sure what to look for.

Are there some specific tests I can conduct ? Or should I just look at some specific statistics such as the R² or the F statistic ?

Comment: Why should the control variable be correlated with your primary variable of interest?

Comment: It's just what I have been told by my teacher. I guess that it helps getting the "true" coefficient of my variable of interest. Like, if I introduce R&D expenditures in my model as a control, and suddenly the coefficient of academic freedom gets smaller, that means that part of the effect on ranking that we attributed to academic freedom was actually due to R&D expenditures. We would not observe this if academic freedom and R&D were not correlated. That's how I see it at least, but I'm far from an expert in the field.

Comment: That has to do with omitted-variable bias, and that is important. However, correlated regression features inflate the standard errors, so your decrease on estimation bias might coincide with an inflation of the estimation variance. I would typically think of a control variable as a way to account for known determinants of the outcome in order to reduce variance and get small standard errors. That feature correlation can lead to variance inflation and bias reduction, along with the usual potential to decrease variance, is part of what makes this a difficult problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I do want to tacle an issue of omitted-variable bias, hence the need for correlation with both X and Y. How could I check whether this omitted variable bias is still there after I introduced my "control" variables ?